# Does an index already cover a clustered primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
  [guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [category] [nvarchar](400)
  {,...other columns}
  )
```

Where `guid` is my primary key, and has a clustered index.

Now, I want an index that *covers* both `category` and `guid`, because I'm rolling up some other stuff related to `t` by category, and I want to avoid including the `t` table itself.

Is it sufficient to create index covering `category`, or do I need to include `guid` as well?

I would expect SQL Server indexes to point directly to page offsets in `t` rather than simply referring to a `guid` primary key value, which means I *would* need to explicitly include the PK column to avoid hitting `t`. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your assumption is **wrong** - all SQL Server non-clustered indices do include the **clustering key** (single or multiple columns) and do **not** point directly at some physical page.

This prevents SQL Server from having to reorganize and update lots of index entries when a page needs to be split in two or relocated. So if you are seeking in a non-clustered index and you find a value, then you have the clustering key and SQL Server will need to do a "bookmark lookup" (or key lookup) to retrieve the actual data page (the leaf page in the clustering index) to get the whole set of data belonging to a single row.

That said - if you ever have a situation where it depends on the ordering of the key columns, then you still might need to create an index specifically on `(guid, category)` - of course, in that case, SQL Server is smart enough to figure out that the clustering key column is already in the index and won't be adding it one more time.

The fact that the clustering key column(s) are inlcuded in every single non-clustered index is another strong reason why your clustering keys should be narrow, static and unique. Making them too wide (anything beyond 8 byte) is a sure recipe for bloat and slow-down.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I thought I was going crazy interpreting the execution plan. Makes sense that the index shouldn't be mucking around with page pointers, even with the tiny performance advantage of avoiding a bookmark lookup. Good point about ordering as well.

Answer (score 1):

Differing slightly to marc_s' answer.

A covering index on (category, guid) will have a different sort on GUID to the primary key sort. Therefore, guid may  appear twice in the index because it is in the key column list and the pointer to the clustered index.

If you INCLUDEd (as a non-key column) guid SQL Server won't add it again.

I can't test the key column thing just now, but I have verified the INCLUDE one before on SQL Server 2005.